# PendingDynamicLinkData is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, invite

I am developing an app which can share and been reward so I use the concept of the dynamic link so to store the information of inviter in that link and later be rewarded. but the PendingDynamicLinkData return null on installing the app after referred.

MainActivity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    checkInvitations();
}

void checkInvitations() {

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        Diagnostics.e(this, "No data").append(activity);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Get the deep link
                    Uri deepLink = data.getLink();

                    // Extract invite
                    FirebaseAppInvite invite = FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(data);
                    if (invite != null) {
                        String invitationId = invite.getInvitationId();
                        Diagnostics.i(this, "Send invitationId to server. InvitationId = " + invitationId).append(activity);
                    }

                    Diagnostics.i(this, "deepLink:" + deepLink).append(activity);

                    if (deepLink != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setPackage(getPackageName());
                        intent.setData(deepLink);

                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
}
```

onClick event on Invite button in MainActivity

```
void onInviteClicked() {

    JSONObject json = jsonObjectCreator.createJSONObjectForSendingUserId(getUserId());
    String jsonString = json.toString();

    getterReferenceId = new GetFromServer(this, GET_REFERENCE_URL, jsonString);
    getterReferenceId.execute();
}
```

GetFromServer class

```
static class GetFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

    private String mUrl;
    private String mSpotsReportJson;
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

    GetFromServer(MainActivity context, String url, String spotsReportJson) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        mUrl = url;
        mSpotsReportJson = spotsReportJson;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) return;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();

        // get JSON
        try {
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(mUrl).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            if (isCancelled()) return null;

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(mSpotsReportJson);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                // Success
                InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                while (inputStreamData != -1) {
                    char current = (char) inputStreamData;
                    inputStreamData = inputStreamReader.read();
                    data.append(current);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionDetails = sw.toString();
            Diagnostics.e(this, "Exception caught: " + exceptionDetails).append(activity);
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data.toString());
            return json;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionDetails = sw.toString();
            Diagnostics.e(this, "Exception caught: " + exceptionDetails).append(activity);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);

                String referenceId = getReferenceIdFromJson(json);

                if (referenceId != null) {
                    // create dynamic link
                    String link = "https://www.hu.info/_invites/" + referenceId;
                    // create Firebase link
                        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                                .setLink(Uri.parse(link))
                                .setDomainUriPrefix("https://hu.page.link")
                                .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
                                .buildShortDynamicLink()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            // Short link created
                                            ShortDynamicLink shortDynamicLink = task.getResult();
                                            if (shortDynamicLink != null) {
                                                Uri shortLink = shortDynamicLink.getShortLink();

                                                // send reference
                                                Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(activity.getString(R.string.invitation_title))
                                                        .setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.invitation_message))
                                                        .setDeepLink(shortLink)
                                                        .setCallToActionText(activity.getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
                                                        .build();                                                            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITE);
                                            } else
                                                Diagnostics.e(this, "ShortDynamicLink is null");
                                        } else
                                            Diagnostics.e(this, "link was not created");
                                    }
                                });
                }
                break;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

<activity android:name=".InfoActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".InvitationActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:host="hu.page.link" android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="hu.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to check the intent on the launch intent - at the moment it looks like you are launching `InfoActivity`, and dynamic links when the app has been installed are going to `InvitationActivity`, but your link checking code is in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Added checkInvitations() method (code the same as in MainActivity) to onCreate() method of InfoActivity, but PendingDynamicLinkData is null in InfoActivity too.

Comment: To confirm, the process you're going through is: click FDL with app not installed, go to play store, install app, go to launcher, launcher app? Or are you hitting the "continue" button in play store?

Comment: Actually app already installed on both devices. I send invitation from device 1 (user 1) to device 2 (user 2). User 2 clicks on the button "install the app" in invitation email. Because app is already installed on device 2 InvitationActivity starts. There I can get FDL and invitation Id. User 2 signs in in InvitationActivity and starts InfoActivity. Than user 1 on device 1 starts app, but PendingDynamikLinkData in his InfoActivity is null.

Comment: User 1 needs to click the link on their device - the link resolution is where the deep link data stored. Just starting the app without having tapped the invite is just a regular app start.

Comment: How can user 1 click the link? Should he go to invitation email which he sent to user 2 and click "instal app" button?

Comment: Changed my implementation. In GetFromServer class in onPostExecute() created short link and then send it. When I click on the link in email and install app from Google Play "start" button appears. I never see "continue" button. What am I doing wrong?